# Image segmentation to locate trees

Tags: qgis, python, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

has anyone a suggestion which segmentation-tool is best suited for this task.
I'm looking for a fast tool to do this approx **1km²/day** the faster the better of course.

I've tried Orfeo's "meanshift" and "exact large meanshift" as well as "watershed", "meanshift" has offered me the best results so far but the whole process is about **5 days for 0.6km²** so i'm looking for a faster way.
spatial resolution is 5-10cm

It doesn't matter if it's with orfeo, saga, grass or just python.

Comment: The measure of area is meaningless without knowing your spatial resolution. ;) What is your ground sample distance?

Comment: @bugmenot123 the spatial resolution is about 5 to 10 cm, i will try resampling it like radouxju suggested.

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: One option to speedup the computation could be to scale the process to be compatible with High Performance Computing architecture. Since version 5.6, OTB offers an elegant way to adapt existing workflow to use MPI to parallelize process over multiple nodes (https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/Request_for_Changes-26:_MPI_Image_File_Writer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most segmentation processes require a lot of processing time, but if you need 5 days for 0.6km² you must have a very high spatial resolution image. By resampling to a coarser pixel size before you run the segmentation algorithm, you should be able to run a lot faster. For trees, 25 cm or even 50 cm is often enough (depending on the tree type).

Comment: the spatial resolution is 5 to 10 cm, so resampling the the image to 25 and 50cm  and further testing should to trick.

Comment: going from 5 to 25 speeds up by 25, so I think that it is a good compromise for you. I mentioned 50 cm but this will only work for large trees.